# Determine if the following sets are definitely compact, definitely closed, both or neither.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Problem 3.3.4 from `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abott. I'd like someone to verify my conclusions, and provide any hints if possible on (b) and (d).

> Assume that $K$ is compact and $F$ is closed. Decide if the following sets are definitely compact, definitely closed, both or neither.

> (a) $K \cap F$

> (b) $\overline{F^C \cap K^C}$

> (c) $K \setminus F = \{x \in K: x \notin F\}$

> (d) $\overline{K \cap F^C}$

***My Attempt.***

Let's assume $F$ is a closed, but unbounded set such as $\mathbf{N}$ or $\mathbf{R}$.

(a) Consider $K \cap F$. $K$ is closed and bounded. $F$ is closed. $K \cap F$ is the finite intersection of closed sets. So, $K \cap F$ is definitely closed.

Also, the intersection of a bounded set with any other set is bounded. So, $K \cap F$ is bounded. Therefore, $K \cap F$ is definitely compact.

(b) Clearly, $\overline{A}$ is closed for any set $A$. So, $\overline{F^C \cap K^C}$ is definitely closed.

(c) If we remove the limit points of $K$, the resulting set $K \setminus F$ could lose closedness. So, we can conclude that it is neither definitely compact, nor definitely close.

(d) $\overline{K \cap F^C}$ is definitely closed.

Comment: For (b), look at $K=F=[0,1]$. Note the set in (d) is a closed subset of $K$.